# how to connect 2 routers to communicate?

Tags: cisco, router, layer1, packet-tracer, interface

What cable connects routers to communicate ?
I am using Packet Tracer Simulator, and I connected 2 routers using a DTE connector. After doing this, I am unable to ping between the 2 routers. Is using a DTE cable the best for connecting routers?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You must be using a serial connection. A serial connection needs the host on one end to be a DTE (Data Terminal Equipment), and the host on the other end to be a DCE (Data Communications Equipment). A DTE talks to a DCE. The router configured as DCE is the one where you set the clock rate and other interface parameters.